# Auditd showing duplicate lines in audit.log

Tags: linux, syslog

I'm having an issue where auditd seems to be logging the same message twice, see below for example:

```
type=EXECVE msg=audit(1495742109.857:90234552): argc=1 a0="/bin/bash"
type=EXECVE msg=audit(1495742109.857:90234552): argc=1 a0="/bin/bash"
```

and here is the relevant configuration:

```
log_file = /var/log/audit/audit.log
log_format = RAW
log_group = root
priority_boost = 4
flush = incremental
freq = 20
num_logs = 3
disp_qos = lossy
dispatcher = /sbin/audispd
name_format = none
name = lga-tag06
max_log_file = 1024
max_log_file_action = rotate
space_left = 75
space_left_action = syslog
action_mail_acct = root
admin_space_left = 50
admin_space_left_action = suspend
disk_full_action = suspend
disk_error_action = suspend
tcp_listen_queue = 5

tcp_max_per_addr = 1
tcp_client_max_idle = 0
enable_krb5 = no
krb5_principal = auditd
```

and the relevant rules:

```
# Default Rule - Delete ALL
-D
enter code here
# Set Buffer size - increase for Busy Systems
-b 8192
enter code here
# Puppet Managed Custom rules begin here:
-b 320
-D
-a exclude,never -F msgtype=PATH 
-a exclude,never -F msgtype=BPRM_FCAPS 
-a exclude,never -F msgtype=CRED_DISP
-a exit,always -F arch=b32 -F euid>=0 -S execve
-a exit,always -F arch=b64 -F euid>=0 -S execve
```

Curious if anyone has seen this before or has any suggestions?

Comment: Hm.. can you please check "lsof /var/log/audit/audit.log" to check how many auditd using this file, I know this looks like ridiculous.. but really have no more actions without more information.

Comment: Hello. A few comments to make you question better: (1) I'm assuming the `enter code here` lines in the rules are a copy/paste error? Or you have those lines in the rules file?  (2) Please include your distribution name and version (3) Include the audit version

Answer (score 0):

I can't say for sure, but until you add the information I requested on the comment to your question, I will go with the following:

> **Note / Update**: This extends to the bounty. Although the comment
>   regarding the *extra lines* doesn't apply, the remaining questions
>   about distribution and versions do.

You might be hitting the ***bug*** reported in [red hat's tracker](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1460459) and in [systemd github](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/959), which state that there is an issue between **auditd** and **systemd's journald**.

The proposed solution there is to disable the audit support from the journal:

```
systemctl mask systemd-journald-audit.socket
```

Before trying it, please read the linked issues above and take all the necessary considerations.